# How to Trigger and handle TextChanged event from Text Box within DataGridColumnHeader in style Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have TextBox resides in DataGridColumnHeader  in style Resource Dictionary, the TextBox used as a Filter so i need to trigger TextChanged event and handle it in View Model to implement filteration process.The point is i need to commit to followinh rules:

1. No Code Behind
2. Event handeling in View Model
3. USe style to be able to apply it for all DataGrids consistently
4. Pass the Event arguments to the View Model to use in filteration process

I did alot of googling but couldn't find solution that commit to all this rules.
Thanks in advance

Edit: Here is the complete xaml of the Resource Dictionary where the Text Box is defined.
      Note: i'm using MVVM Light EventToCommand trying to bind the TextChanged event of 
            the text box to Attached Behavior in the View Model
            Also note that this xamle still under development and modification knowing that 
            i got most of it from DataGrid Filtering Application

```
enter code here
    <ResourceDictionary x:Class="PreCommissioning.Infrastructure.Filter2.FilteringDataGrid"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"      
 xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"                   
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PreCommissioning.Infrastructure.Filter2;assembly=PreCommissioning.Infrastructure"
 xmlns:localx="clr-namespace:PreCommissioning.Module.Subsystem.ViewModel;assembly=PreCommissioning.Module.Subsystem"    
 xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
>

    <local:HeaderFilterConverter x:Key="headerConverter"/>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="ShowFilterControl">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="filterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="filterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="White"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="HideFilterControl">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="filterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="filterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Black"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="#00000000"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <my:DataGridHeaderBorder x:Name="dataGridHeaderBorder" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="31" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource headerConverter}">
                                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                <Binding ElementName="filterTextBox" Path="Text" />
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Content" />
                                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </ContentPresenter.Content>
                                </ContentPresenter>

                            <!--Filter Text Box-->    
                            <TextBox x:Name="filterTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                         MinWidth="25" Height="Auto" OpacityMask="Black" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                         Text="" 
                                         TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TextChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                                             PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                                             CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=Name}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </TextBox>

                        </Grid>
                        </my:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ShowFilterControl_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowFilterControl}"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="HideFilterControl_BeginShowFilterControl"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="HideFilterControl_BeginShowFilterControl" Storyboard="{StaticResource HideFilterControl}"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ShowFilterControl_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#00FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA"/>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
        <!--

        -->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Can you post the xaml where your text box is defined?

Comment: also, are you using a MVVM framework, if so which one?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to trigger and handle the textchanged event ?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a very similar filter text in my app. And it works with the Command, taking parameter as the current text. I hope this is what you were looking for (kinda late to see this question still being unanswered all these years)

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Filter names by " ></Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtFilter" Width="290" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FilterItemsCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

and in the respective ViewModel, i have the below lines of code to make use of the filter operation.

ViewModel constructor:

```
FilterItemsCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => FilterItems(), _ => CanFilterItems);
FilterText = string.Empty;
```

and the filter command logic:

```
    [NotifyPropertyChanged]
    public string FilterText { get; set; }
    public ICommand FilterItemsCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void FilterItems()
    {
        // to load the items from source so every filter change will be from the source. 
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterText))
            PopulateItems(); //imagine i am loading a set of items from source to display in the UI
        else PopulateItems(filter: FilterText);
    }

    public bool CanFilterItems
    {
        get
        {
            return (Items != null);
        }
    }
```

And If you are interested on the PopulateItems method,

```
private void PopulateLaunchItems(string filter = "")
    {
        // Add items
        Items = new ObservableCollection<SomeItemType>();

        // use your filter to manipulate the data from source
        ...
        ...
    }
```

This is a working piece of code. I hope this may help someone in the future even if the original person asked might have moved on. ;-)